# Сохранение velocity по модулю при столкновении Unity 2D

Tags: unity3d

Есть 3 объекта которым я задаю случайное направление и скорость:

```
    public float MaximumImpulseAtDirection = 1;
    void Start()
    {
        float xImpulse = Random.Range(-MaximumImpulseAtDirection, MaximumImpulseAtDirection);
        float yImpulse = Random.Range(-MaximumImpulseAtDirection, MaximumImpulseAtDirection);
        GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = new Vector2(xImpulse, yImpulse);
    }
```

Проблема в том, что когда они сталкиваются, то замедляются, и в итоге вовсе останавливаются

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я хочу, чтобы их "импульс" сохранялся (не знаю, как это по другому назвать)

Comment: может скорость, а не импульс?

Comment: Liner и Angular Drag в настройках RigidBody в 0 поставь, если они не таковы

Comment: @Methorn выставил, никакого эффекта

Comment: @Methorn в физике есть закон сохранения импульса в изолированной системе, а про скорость я такого не знаю

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я правильно понял то в каждом Rigidbody нужно поставить в Collision Detection>Continuous что бы они не проходили сквозь коллайдеры, так же можно по желанию добавить физический материал (Physics Material 2D) и в физическом материале добавить минимум отскоков в Bounciness 0.01, это так для на всякий случай. Или не использовать velocity а AddForce:

```
  GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce (new Vector2(xImpulse, yImpulse));
```

Или

```
 GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(new Vector2(xImpulse, yImpulse),ForceMode2D.Impulse);
```

[image: Скрин]

Comment: Измена velocity на AddForce не дала эффекта, а вот танцы с Bounciness действительно помогли